# CoreBluetooth How to save pairing in my code

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

Am working in core bluetooth framework, I have connecting my iPhone to embedded BLE4.0 supported device with out any protection. Now they have changed the connection request with pairing key every time while connecting to device its asking pairing key but i want to hardcode it into inside the application and need to use that for while connecting with out user interaction.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Please post the problematic section of the code.

Comment: Its not in code, framework itself taking care of giving alert to user while connecting but i need to do it manually,

Comment: This is not a CoreBluetooth framework problem. If anything, its the device's firmware.

Comment: For that we can do anything manually.